# How does Myouga Unzen's "Math Language" work?

Tags: medaka-box

Just recently I have watched both seasons of Medaka Box. I think it was in the early second season where Myouga Unzen first appeared and spoke in numbers. I don't know if it was just in my case, but not all of her lines were translated, so I thought that it might be interesting to know, if it's possible to translate it or if the numbers are just randomly put there.

If it's possible, please show me how or give me a reference to where it's described how to.

Comment: Well, would have to have a list of her phrases and the numbers assigned to it to know weather they are random or not in first place. `4136163735641? means "Did You Think You Were the Strongest Here or Something?" (お前最強ってなんだと思う？, Omae Saikyō tte Nanda to Omou?) in Myouga Unzen's self-created language.` Looking at this example `Omae` and `Omou` are assigned to 41

Comment: There is only 1 line "untranslated", as far as I know, both in the manga and anime, which the line (first ever?) she spoke after appearing and knocking down Medaka. I don't watch/follow this series so there might be more, but I think that line is *the one*: 564212412097135 163845618641984 612401842619842 617246109842671 927481124124 2354!

Comment: If someone is proficient in Japanese, they can try researching it with keywords "めだかボックス 数字言語". I found a link to Japanese Yahoo! Answers [here](http://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/tag/tags.php?tag=%E6%95%B0%E5%AD%97%E8%A8%80%E8%AA%9E). There is a [list of words](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1240057227), but eventually, some just answered "It's a random number".

Comment: You can use this http://homepage3.nifty.com/tawarayutaka/ipage/suujigengo/eumazeu4103641.html and try to find out the answer. You will need to find the missing number translate them into Japanese, and translate them back into English.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but it's not the words that are being used, because in the English dub, both "I'll have to attack again!" and "Here's one more!" come from "21487214". Therefore it might have something to do with the intent of the words being said as both phrases have an aggressive intent.

Comment: The English dub is translated from the original Japanese and sometimes is given creative freedom to modify the script, so it might not be the *real* translation.